# Mention and Current Date in POST https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/edit-document

Tags: quip, liveapps

I am using the Quip API to edit documents but I would like to @mention a user and use @current date too.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Carlos, welcome to SFSE. I know there are some people here working on Quip but it's not a very common expertise. Expanding your question (in accordance with our general expectations) to show what you're doing so far and link to the documentation involved might smooth the path to an answer.

Comment: @DavidReed I'm not happy that I'm seeing many questions that relate to parts of Salesforce that ARE parts of Salesforce (but may not be part of the core platform) being marked as off-topic. This is VERY MUCH on-topic, as it is asking how to use a Salesforce API to mention a user, which is similar to asking how to do that with the Chatter API.

Comment: @DavidSchach I have not voted to close this question - I actually agree with you that Quip is on topic. I apologize if my comment was not expressed clearly; my intention was to encourage Carlos to *flesh out* his question in order to best take advantage of relatively less-common Quip expertise in the community.